# Why is CSS imported into JSX files instead of being loaded separately?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm not asking how to import CSS into JSX code - there are many guides. I'm asking why. For context I'm learning React; I'm new to React and still fairly new to Javascript and the whole area of web development. I'm sure this will turn out to be a naive question, but I can't find the answer.

All the React tutorials I've looked at use JSX (understandably) and all seem to install a library such as `css-loader` and then include an import statement such as `import "./index.css"` in the JSX file itself.

I would assume it's also possible just to load the `index.css` file, old-school, directly into the HTML and still have it apply the exact same styling based on classnames and IDs I add to my JSX components. What's the advantage, if any, to importing the CSS into the Javascript or JSX file itself? It seems to be a universal practice.

Comment: So that webpack adds the css file in the dependency tree.

Comment: Mainly for maintainablity. Having everything in one massive file becomes a mess pretty fast. Your changes will not be scalable. However you have to practice the modular css approach when importing the css in your components. Another interesting concept is the use of CSS in JS: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+in+js&oq=css+in+js&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j35i39j0.2998j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8